# main and branch are entirely different commit histories

Tags: github, graph, branch, git-branch, pull-request

This is my git graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhHZV.png)

Where the graph was disconnected, I changed the file I was working on. I was working on the file A by connecting it to origin, but I disconnected A's origin and created a new file B, and then connected the origin to this file. So I think that's why graph is disconnected. The problem is when I do PR, I get an error saying "main and branch are entirely different commitment histories." What should I do if I want to connect those two and do PR?

- I don't think it's a matter of main and master's branches. I already changed it to main.